# Execute code if condition is met or error occurs

Tags: python, if-statement, error-handling

Is there a way in python to have an if statement, that will execute if the condition is met or an error occurs in testing it, but not if it just tests false.

(Fictional) Example:

```
ErrIf 12/x % 2 ==0:
    Print('Yes')
```

Expected behavior:

x=3 -> Yes

x=4 ->

x=0 -> Yes

I know I can do the following:

```
try:
    if condition:
        do stuff
except:
    do same stuff
```

but this violates the DRY principle so I'm wondering if there's a simpler way.

Comment: Is there a use case ?  Other than DRY, it seems somewhat obscure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Raise an exception when the condition is met.

```
try:
    if condition:
        raise Exception("Dummy")
except:
    do stuff
```